# Avoiding existence errors

Tags: django

```
def clean_bank_account(self):
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    ssn = self.form.cleaned_data.get('ssn')
    customer = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(ssn=ssn)

    bank_account = self.form.cleaned_data.get('bank_account')
    bank = self.form.cleaned_data.get('bank')
    bank_transit = self.form.cleaned_data.get('bank_transit')
    qs = FinancialProfile.objects.filter(
        bank=bank,
        bank_transit=bank_transit,
        bank_account=bank_account)

    if customer.count() == 1:
        for cust in customer:
            qs = qs.exclude(customer_id=cust.id)
    if qs.count() > 0:
        # The concatenation of bank transit, the bank account and the bank
        # number must be unique. Hence, the following message would be
        # displayed if it is already in use.
        raise ValidationError(
            _('The bank, the bank transit and the bank are already in use.')
        )

    if bank not in (None, ''):
            # Check bank account format for specific banks
            length = settings.LOANWOLF_BANK_ACCOUNTS_LENGTH.get(bank)
            if length:
                if bank_transit not in (None, ''):
                    if not bank_account.isnumeric() or length != len(bank_account):
                        raise ValidationError(
                            _('Bank account number must contain %d digits') % length  # noqa
                        )
                else:
                    raise ValidationError(
                        _('Cannot validate bank account without a valid bank transit')  # noqa
                    )
    return bank_account
```

I would like to improve the structure of this code. I can't do `CustomerProfile.objects.get(ssn=ssn)`, because it will give me an error if the object doesn't exist. Instead I decided to create a list with a filter which returns me a queryset. with the lines

```
if customer.count() == 1:
        for cust in customer:
            qs = qs.exclude(customer_id=cust.id)
```

will exclude the customer id if there exists only one customer in the list. At the beginning, I thought I could remove the for loop and just using customer, but I can't since it is a queryset. I tought I could do Is there a way to improve this part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop can be replaced by [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut) filter

```
 qs = qs.exclude(customer_id__in=[cust.id for cust in customer])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I will accept your question. Questions : How many years have you been doing Django? When did you start being comfortable with this framework? How old are you?

Comment: Let's talk on chat if you want to talk something that's not related to question https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150105/know-one

Comment: I can't, my rating is not enough higher. Just answer it and delete it 5 minutes later maybe

Comment: I am currently student with one year experience with Django. If you don't have rating and you want to connect then you can connect on LinkedIn or fb. Go to http://arpitsolanki.in  you will find my contacts there. Don't delete the question if it helped you then accept the answer.

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: Around 20. Still a student